# Correct "stripes" in VHS record

Tags: video-quality, filter, virtualdub, vhs

Recently I recorded my old VHS tapes to my hard disk. There is one thing bothering me concerning the video quality. Whenever the camera moves, the motion produces visible "stripes" in the picture:

[image]

It seems like each line is shifted. Can this be corrected by a filter? If yes, what filter can I use? I prefer virtualdub for editing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are interlacing artifacts. They become visible when the motion in the video is faster than the field rate, so that when both fields are combined into a progressive scan image, the movement is visible in a single frame. They can be removed with a de-interlace filter. I've never personally used one with Virtualdub, but several are available:

- [MSU](http://compression.ru/video/deinterlacer/index_en.html)
- [Smart Deinterlace](http://rationalqm.us/smart/smart.html)
- [vddeint](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vddeint/)
- [Various older ones](http://www.guthspot.se/video/)